# populate_sdk fails when multilib enabled

Tags: linux, sdk, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to generate SDK using yocto.

Hardware: x64

generic meta-intel layer

Image: core-image-minimal.

I enabled multilib in the conf file to support 32 bit libraries.

```
require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "x86"
```

When I run the following command: `bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-minimal`, I am getting the following error at the last stage.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32-packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target : Depends: lib32-glibc-gconv-cp1252 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-glibc-gconv-ibm850 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-glibc-gconv-iso8859-1 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-glibc-gconv-iso8859-15 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-glibc-localedata-i18n but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libatomic-dev but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libatomic1 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libc6 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libc6-dbg but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libc6-dev but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libc6-thread-db but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libc6-utils but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libgcc-s-dev but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libgcc1 but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libsegfault but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libstdc++-dev but it is not installable
                                                 Depends: lib32-libstdc++6 but it is not installable
                                                 Recommends: lib32-libssp-dev but it is not installable
                                                 Recommends: lib32-libssp0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
```

How can I resolve this error. I see a similar post in yocto mailing list..

https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2017-October/038338.html

Thanks for your time.. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: What's value of `SDK_MACHINE` variable ?

Comment: I don't see any such variable in my local.conf

Comment: I assigned SDKMACHINE ?= "i686", even I got the same error..

Comment: How can I solve this.. Is there any hint

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine solved this by changing `conf/local.conf` like this:

```
# packaging
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_ipk"
#PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb package_ipk"
```

it seems that package_deb is part of the problem.

Of course it leaves as many questions as it answers, but maybe enough to get you past your current block.

Comment: This really worked for me. Very weird. Thanks a lot.